# Not able to run Hazelcast in AWS enabled mode

Tags: server, hazelcast, tcp

I am getting following error on starting hazelcast server using server.sh in all the versions 3.1.7, 3.2.6, 3.3.3

Error while creating AWSJoiner!
***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.cluster.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS***

Multicast and tcp-ip are working fine
Hazelcast-all and all other jars are included in the lib.

Answer (score 2):

Did you include 'hazelcast-cloud' jar. This is needed to use AWS discovery.